# Invalid operands to binary (have float and float)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float n,f;
    printf("n too:");
    scanf("%f",&n);
    f=sqrt(n);
    f=n%f;
    printf("%f",f);
    return(0);
}
```

It iss my code. But i get this "Invalid operands to binary (have float and float)" error in 9th line.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operands of `%` must be of integer type. You should use the library function `fmod`.

#### C11: 7.12.10.1 The fmod functions

> #### Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <math.h>
> double fmod(double x, double y);
> float fmodf(float x, float y);
> long double fmodl(long double x, long double y);
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> The `fmod` functions compute the floating-point remainder of `x/y`.

Comment: Why suggest the `fmod()` set of functions rather than the `remainder()` set to perform like the integer remainder `%`?  `fmod()` may be a better fit, but it deserves noting.

Comment: @chux; Both sets of functions are different (slightly).

Comment: Nitpick, it is not just `int` but integer types of several kind would do.

Comment: @JensGustedt; Thanks. Actually I meant to say that :)